# How to find tips about The Forgotten

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I would like to know how can I find out **in the game** how do I unlock The Forgotten?

I mean, I know there are plenty of places where they say how to unlock, but I would like to know if there is a way to find it playing.

The creator ( Edmund McMillen ) said

> “You cheaters have no sense of adventure!”  “Just play the game and explore!”

But I have already played quite a bit and no clue so far, so I would appreciate a kick off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Forgotten is a secret character in BoI:Afterbirth+, only made available with the most recent "booster pack". As with several other secret characters in past expansions, there are almost no signs of his existence in-game. In fact, the only sign that there's something hidden at all is if manage to beat the first floor boss in under a minute, which will cause Mom to call out Isaac's name. Once you've done this, you need to explore (as Edmund mentioned in his tweet) the first floor very carefully and make note of any differences. Other than that, a typical player who doesn't already know about the Forgotten would probably never find out about it.

Comment: BTW, your previous answer was waaaaaay better, don't know why you changed it.

Comment: @carla I know it was way better. But I was downvoted because you specified in your question that the answer must come from in-game, and my answer came from outside sources. So after some discussion with others, I changed my answer to accommodate them.

Answer (score -3):

You have to kill the first boss on the floor in 60 seconds and then after Mom yells “Isaac!” run back to the room you spawned in, drop a bomb in the middle, and it’ll drop A Broken Shovel (which causes moms foot to drop down as long as you’re holding it, until it’s activated which pauses it for that room you’re in) and then you have to proceed to kill Mom, pick up the negative, complete the Boss Rush, continue until you reach The Dark Room. From there, find an empty room with crumbling dirt in the center, use the shovel, and then boom. The Forgotten is unlocked.

Comment: The question is not asking for yet another set of instructions. It asks what hints there are in the game which help someone to figure out this sequence of steps on their own.